# new keyword in java

Tags: java, inheritance

New to java, and still struggling with new keyword and inheritance:

```
public class A1 {
    void a_method (){
        System.out.println("Inside A1 method");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class A2 extends A1{
    void a_method(){
        System.out.println("Inside A2 method");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestA1A2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A1 a1 = new A1();
        A1 a2 = new A2();  //not sure if it created object of A1 or A2
        A2 a3 = new A2();

        a1.a_method();
        a2.a_method();
        a3.a_method();

    }
}
```

---

i am struggling to understand the new keyword and if in the above code:

```
A1 a2 = new A2();  //not sure if it created object of A1 or A2
```

will a2 be an object of A1 or A2? from the output i can see that it called the method of A2, but i really dont get the new keyword. And as A2 is extending A1, is it possile to call the method of A1??

Comment: You can read about `Polymorphism` here: http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html

Comment: @prabh check my answer once

Comment: @prabh check my answer  i updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
A1 a2 = new A2();
```

This code creates a A2 object but you can only access to methods of A1 class with a2. If a method is overriden in A2, this is the method of A2 which is called.

Comment: but the output of the A1 a2 = new A2(); resulted in Inside A2 method which states that it was accessing A2 method and not A1

Comment: @Thierry it is wrong.sub class method will be called.But he said suped class method is called

Comment: @Thierry
it is partially correct, it can access methods of A1 only is incorrect because if same name exists in A2 also, it overrides.

Answer (score 2):

You created a new A2() object, because you said 'new A2()'. Since A2 is also an A1, you can refer to it like it's an A1:

```
A1 a1 = new A2();
A2 a2 = new A2();
```

In the above example, in a1, you can call all the methods of A1 on a1.
For a2, you can call all the methods of a1 AND a2 on it, since you inherited the methods of A1.

Comment: what is the significane of A1 a2 then?? i am not sure of this

Comment: I've updated my example. Does this make it more clear? It's the type of the object you are instantiating using the 'new' keyword.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). Since `A2` extends `A1`, you can declare `A1` as `A2` and that will give you access to all of the non overriden methods inside `A1` and all the overriden `A1` methods inside `A2` (btw its a good practice to use the `@Override` annotation when you override).

In this case, because `A2` overrides `a_method()` when you do `a2.a_method()` you'll be accessing `A2's` version of `a_method()`.

An explanation from the javadoc:

> The dictionary definition of polymorphism refers to a principle in
>   biology in which an organism or species can have many different forms
>   or stages. This principle can also be applied to object-oriented
>   programming and languages like the Java language. Subclasses of a
>   class can define their own unique behaviors and yet share some of the
>   same functionality of the parent class.

Comment: Since A2 extends A1, you can declare A1 as A2 and that will give you access to all of the methods for A2, aswell as A1.

the above statement seems incorrect, as a method declared just in A2 wont be accessible using the statement A1 a2 = new A2();

Answer (score 2):

A1 a2 = new A2(); 
This will create an object of type A2.

Here what happen is..

You are creating an Object of type A2 and assign in to a reference of type A1.
When you execute new A2(), it'll invoke the constructor **A2()**(which is the default constructor) and create an Object of type A2.

```
public class A2 extends A1{
     public A2(){
       super();
     }

    void a_method(){
        System.out.println("Inside A2 method");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `A2` extends `A1`, `A2` *is* an `A1`.  It is a *specialized type* of `A1`.  It is everything an `A1` is, but there's probably something unique about `A2`.  An analogy would be how a cat IS a mammal.  In Java-speak, `Cat` would extend `Mammal`.

```
A1 a2 = new A2();
```

This line creates an instance of `A2` because of `new A2()`.  However, the tricky bit here is that going forward, it's going to be treated like an `A1` because of `A1 a2 =`.  Let me remove one little bit of noise from the line:

```
A1 xx = new A2();
```

This is exactly the same, but the resulting object is called `xx`.  Thus, we're creating a instance of the `A2` class, we're calling it `xx`, and going forward, we'll be treating it like an `A1`.

Answer (score 1):

A1 is the parent class of A2,

```
A1 a2 = new A2();
```

Creates an instance of A2 whose parent class is A1. But because A2 inherited from A1, a2 is also A1.

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit from a class in Java the inherited class is reffered to as the super class. Think of it as the more general class. The class that inherits is more specialised.

```
A1 a2 = new A2();
```

in this case a2 (type A1) is the general class and by doing the operation you make it of a more specialised type defined in A2

Answer (score 0):

`A2` object **is** (extended) `A1` object too. So you can use it as `A2` **and** as `A1`.

Comment: but the methods of A2 wont be accessible with statement A1 a2 = new A2(); and only methods of A1 will be accessible.